# Swift Tableview search result cell selection checkmark not saving after clearing the search result

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, searchbar

In myscenario, I am listing `JSON` data into Tableview with help of `codable`. Here, I have a Tableview and `searchBar` with filter array. Also, implemented tableview multiple cell selection with `checkmark` options. Here, without search the selected cell checkmark `persistant` working fine but if I search particular data and selecting cell the checkmark is showing but after clear the search result `(fileterarray to tableviewarray)` the checkmark not showing (Its mean selected cell checkmark not persisted and not showing after clear search result) . Somewhere I am doing mistakes in my codebase. Please correct it and provide a solid solution.

Actual operation and issue is need to allow user to selected their cell by checkmark enable with and without search. Without search everything working fine but with search the selected check not persisting...

**JSON Codable**

```
// MARK: - TeamListRoot
struct TeamListRoot: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let data: [TeamListData]
}

// MARK: - TeamListData
struct TeamListData: Codable, Hashable {
    let userid: String?
    let firstname, designation: String?
    let profileimage: String?
    var isSelected = false

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case userid, firstname, designation, profileimage
    }
}
```

**My Tableview and SearchBar Collections**

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchbar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var searching = false
var membersData = [TeamListData]()
var filteredData = [TeamListData]()
```

**My Tableview Delegates**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searching ? filteredData.count : membersData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell:TeamlistCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! TeamlistCustomCell
       let textForRow = searching ? filteredData[indexPath.row] : membersData[indexPath.row]
       cell.empName.text = textForRow.firstname
       cell.designationLabel.text = textForRow.designation
       cell.accessoryType = textForRow.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
       return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
       if  searching == false {
           membersData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
       } else {
           filteredData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
       }
       tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
       let selectedAreas = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected}
}
```

**SearchBar Delegates**

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
      self.searchbar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
      searching = true
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
      self.searchbar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
      searching = false
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
      searching = false
      self.searchbar.resignFirstResponder()
      self.searchbar.text = ""
      filteredData.removeAll()
      self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
       searching = false
       self.searchbar.resignFirstResponder()
       self.searchbar.text = ""
       filteredData.removeAll()
       self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
       if !searchText.isEmpty {
           filteredData = membersData.filter({ ($0.firstname?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText))! })
           searching = true
        } else {
            filteredData.removeAll()
            searching = false
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: @vadian Could you please check this question? provide me a answer please

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

//Replace your **Array** declaration

```
var membersData: [TeamListData] = [TeamListData]()
var filteredData: [TeamListData] = [TeamListData]()
```

//Replace **didSelectRowAt** code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.tblSearch.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if  searching == false {

        if let row = self.membersData.firstIndex(where: { $0.userid == membersData[indexPath.row].userid }) {

            membersData[row].isSelected.toggle()
        }
    } else {

        if let row = self.membersData.firstIndex(where: { $0.userid == filteredData[indexPath.row].userid }) {

           membersData[row].isSelected.toggle()
        }

        if let row = self.filteredData.firstIndex(where: { $0.userid == filteredData[indexPath.row].userid }) {

            filteredData[row].isSelected.toggle()
        }
    }

    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: Awesome bro. Thank you so much. I will try and update you here.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is that I set the selection after reloading the tableView in WillDisplay cell.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let contact = contactsFiltered[indexPath.row]
    if selectedContacts.contains(contact) {
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    } else {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }
    }
```

I just need to keep my contactsFiltered up to date

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let contactToAppend = contactsFiltered[indexPath.row]
        selectedContacts.append(contactToAppend)
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let contactCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ContactTVCell {
            if let contactToDelete = contactCell.contact {
                selectedContacts.removeAll(where: { $0 == contactToDelete})
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling is select from filteredData While you are searching . 
when you are done , you load items from membersData . in membersData you dont have selected rows

change this :

```
 if  searching == false {
           membersData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
       } else {
           filteredData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
       }
```

to this one :

```
      membersData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
       filteredData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your post. I have one doubt here, If suppose already selected checkmark in membersData if user search same data then filteredData again chance to allow a checkmark duplication? because every selection I am adding selected cell data into array for some other process. Also, I ma clearing search result array every searchbar cancel button click. So above solution not enough I think :)

Comment: i dont know what do you mean by duplicate checkmark . if you search the same text then the prev Rows that you have checked before must be checked in the search result . just try and debug , i don't know what are you doing exactly

Comment: I tried above code but still it is not working. Could you please check my searchbar delegations once again because I think there I codeded some mistakes.

Comment: it should work.. i don't know what is wrong with your code . btw why you clear filtered data when searchbutton pressed ?